# How to run upsert in salesforce using firstname + lastname + email

Tags: integration, upsert, informatica

I am using salesforce object as target in Informatica. The source is a csv file. I want to run upsert function in salesforce with a matching criteria Firstname + Lastname + Email. Right now I have Firstname, lastname, email as three different columns in csv file. When I go to informatica and select the matching criteria, it gives me option to only select one field.

How do I match on Firstname + Lastname + Email?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add expression as external Id field in Informatica field mapping like this:

1. In Salesforce, Create a text field of unique, external Id type.
2. In Informatica, Choose operation type as: Upsert (Update or Insert)
3. In Informatica, field Mapping map the external Id field to this expression  `Firstname||'_'||Lastname||'_'||Email`

Now Informatica will check the uniqueness of concatenated string, if there is already a match it will update otherwise create a new record

Comment: Thank you so much for the step by step instructions. I was able to follow it through. Quick question: Would it work for existing records? I have few records already existing in Salesforce. If I add this logic now, would it match on the existing records?

Comment: First you will have to update the external id field for existing record either through dataloader or Apex anonymous window script

Comment: quick question how is the above expression you mentioned different than concat(Firstname,Lastname,Email)? In your expression are we appending '_' in between firstname, lastname and then between lastname and email?